# Best way to save multiple datatables for later use

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable

I currently have a mysql Database with multiple tables.
Some of my tables has over 10000 rows. 
Now I wonder, what is the best way to store the tables that I get from the db to get access to them from different ViewModels.

Right now I use variables like this in the ViewModel of my program:

```cs
private DataTable _EmployeeList;
```

And I only want to load that data from the database if I really need it to not use too much of my RAM. After the first load, I keep them stored in  RAM to get better performance on the next access.

I thought about creating a new class where I can store them in static variables. (But here is the problem of loading the data with different joins --> too much data that is not needed everywhere) 
Or using a DataSet where I can add the table to the set if I need them.

But are there any better ways to achieve the goal? Or is one of my ideas good enough?

**Edit** 
The tables are only updated after the user adds / edits or deletes a datarow. 
 
To be more clear, I have a UI that shows all the data that is stored in the tables (I use a DataGrid for that). Some of the data has foreign keys, that's why I use inner joins to get the the name out of the the second table for the visual content. 
 
The DataGrid load is pretty slow but that's another topic. 
Also I don't want to request the the server all the time to get the same data over and over again. That's why I wanna save the data in the ram.

Comment: 10,000 rows is *tiny*. If you have performance/data-szie problems with so little data you have a bigger problem. Do you have indexes? Are you filtering data in memory rather than in the query?

Comment: There's a couple of other factors we need to know. Such as how frequently is this data updated? If so, what sort of frequency would be reasonable to reload the data? You talk about multiple tables, could some of those be updated more frequently than others?

Comment: This data that has different joins? how do you get it? could you show the code? it seems to me that a regular query for this purpose may be more than enough

Comment: Unless you have huge latency let the database do its job.

Comment: MySQL INNODB tables naturally READ ONCE and then avoid READing data again when possible.  innodb_buffer_pool_size is a major player in this concept of operation.  
Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

*(This answer is a frame challenge.)*

There is a tool that does exactly what you need: It can

- load data from storage,
- cache frequently used data in RAM, and
- perform filter or JOIN operations *extremely* efficiently.

It's called a *database management system* (DBMS), and, luckily, you already have one in use: MySQL.

No, seriously, what you are trying to re-implement in C# is *exactly* what database systems like MySQL are designed to do!

If (re-)loading employees from your database is really the bottleneck of your application, there is a lot of fine-tuning that you can do on the database level: Do you have indexes that match your query patterns? Are your cache settings appropriate?

Yes, database optimization takes some time, but it usually takes *way less* time than trying to re-implement all those features in your application.

Comment: The thing is, that I use the MVVM pattern and need to get the DB Data in different ViewModels and Views. Abviously I could do in every ViewModel a new DataTable variable but I would have in some of them the same data. Which is, in my opinion, useless memory use for the same data. So I wan't to "cache" it manually.

Comment: @PaRcS: Unless you are developing software for a tiny, RAM-constrained device, this is wasted effort. Only load the data you need from the DB. If you show 100 employees per page, load those 100 employees. And if you need to load those 100 employees again later, so be it, the garbage collector will take care of cleaning up the memory required for the first 100 employees when the time comes. RAM is cheap, developer time is expensive. Spend your time on more useful optimizations.

Comment: @PaRcS Use MARIADB (at least 90 days after STABLE) and you will have Query Cache available that works and can frequently be 'touchless' in getting the data you need.  You are contemplating building a secondary nightmare that will only consume your days (if you continue on this path).